# auto-increment value in trigger

Tags: mysql

how to get the value of auto increment in `before insert trigger` ? in case I have to make an automatically `user.id` by `concat` the auto increment row with the gender row for each new member..

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to do it reliably in before insert trigger. You can only be sure of what AI value was assigned to a new row **after** it has been inserted.

Comment: To the person who voted this answer down, read the documentation! e.g. "In a BEFORE trigger, the NEW value for an AUTO_INCREMENT column is 0, not the sequence number that is generated automatically when the new row actually is inserted."

Answer (score 0):

The command [`SHOW TABLE STATUS`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/show-table-status.html) will give you details about all tables in a database.

An example in PHP to retrieve the next AI of a table (`my_db.my_table`):

```
$sth = $dbh->prepare('SHOW TABLE STATUS FROM `my_db` WHERE `Name` = ?');
$sth->execute(array("my_table"));
$result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$sth->closeCursor();

printf("Next Auto_increment is: %d\n", $result['Auto_increment']);
```

Obviously, this is to give you a general idea how to retrieve the desired AI value. In a trigger, you'd have to resort to a cursor to retrieve this information.

Comment: Despite downvote on my answer I will reiterate, that this gives no guarantee that this AI will be the one used for next INSERT into that table.

Comment: Maybe not in the context of a trigger which wouldn't be able to lock the corresponding table for write operations to *reliably* retrieve the next AI. Used in a different context (lock, read status, insert, unlock) it might, though.